# Find elements by CSS class

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery code:

```
$.fn.slider = function () {

  $(this).each(function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    var $items = $this.find("div.poster");
    console.log($items.length);  
    $items.first().addClass("active");
    console.log($items.find(".active").length);  

  });
}
```

This is withing a plugin Slider which I apply as follows:

```
$("div.posters").slider();
```

And I get the following output:

```
$items.length = 2
$items.find(".active").length = 0
```

How is this possible? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I am posting the HTML code as requested:

```
<div class="posters">    
  <div class="poster">
    Poster 1
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    Poster 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel `$items` contains the class to itself and that is the problem. `find` only gets decendants. [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/find/) **Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.**

Comment: Could you show related html or short example?

Comment: I think `$items.first().addClass("active")` would effect on jquery element and not on `$items` list objects

Comment: @SilverSurfer I just added the HTML code and more plugin code

Answer (score 1):

Change `$this` for `$(this)`:

```
var $items = $(this).find("div.poster");
```

Comment: That didn't work ... I updated with more code to give a bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs - Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a `new jQuery object from the first element in that set`.

Can you try like this:

```
$(this).each(function () {

  var $this = $(this);

  var $items = $this.find("div.poster");
  console.log($items.length);  
  $items.first().addClass("active");
  console.log($items.filter(".active").length);  
  console.log($this.children(".active").length);
});
```

Comment: I get `console.log($items.find(".active").length);` as 0

Comment: Updated to use `filter` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the [DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/find/), `find` cannot find the class applied to element itself to which `find` is applied, but the class that is present in it's descendant elements.

> **Description**: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or
>   element.

So, if you wish to use `find`, then go through it's parent like:

```
$(this).each(function () {

  var $this = $(this);

  var $items = $this.find("div.poster");
  console.log($items.length);  
  var temp = $items.first();
  temp.addClass("active");
  console.log(temp.parents(".posters").find(".active").length);  // Will give 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I think is the best way to go:

```
$items.filter(".active").length
```

Comment: You can also use `$this.children(".active").length` to get the length. Please check for answer above.